# 'Ticker' object has no attribute 'replace' en pdr.get_data_yahoo

Tags: python, pandas

Intento descargar información acerca de una acción. El código corre perfecto si en data ejecuto con `data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("goog", start, end)` pero si quiero utilizar otro ticker tengo que escribirlo dentro del código y mi idea es que el usuario pueda cambiarlo indicándolo desde el principio.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf

yf.pdr_override()

ticker = input("Por favor indica el ticker de la acción que deseas: ")
ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)

# FECHAS PARA PRECIOS
start = input(print("Indica la fecha inicial en formato AAAA-MM-DD: "))
end = input(print("Indica la fecha final en formato AAAA-MM-DD: "))
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("goog", start, end)

# INFORMACIÓN Y PRECIOS HISTÓRICOS
print(ticker.info)
print(data)
```

Si intento cambiar el último renglón de "fechas para precios" y poner ticker en vez del ticker en específico ("goog" en este caso) no lo ejecuta, me dice que no tiene el atributo de reemplazar ('Ticker' object has no attribute 'replace'): me parece que es porque no puede reemplazar el ticker por el que le estoy diciendo que ponga como input. ¿Saben cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Dejo un ejemplo de qué es lo que no funciona y el mensaje de error:

Mensaje:
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Ticker' object has no attribute 'replace'
File "(ruta)", line 11, in 
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)

Código donde falla:

```
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
```

Comment: Buen día, honestamente no se entiende la pregunta ¿Podrías explicar o agregar el ejemplo que no funciona?

Comment: Listo, mi estimado, puse lo que falla, el mensaje de error y la parte del código donde no funciona específicamente.

Comment: ¡Ya lo pude resolver! Por si a alguien le sirve sólo declaré la acción como otra variable:

stock = input("Por favor indica el ticker de la acción que deseas: ")
ticker = yf.Ticker(stock)